# оптимизация сборки webpack & angular 2

Tags: angularjs, webpack

написал вот такой сборщик

```
'use strict';

var DEVELOPMENT = 'development';
var PRODUCTION = 'production';

var NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV === PRODUCTION ? PRODUCTION : DEVELOPMENT;

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var precss = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ts'),
        vendor: [
            'core-js/client/shim',
            'zone.js',
            'reflect-metadata',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations',
            '@angular/material'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        //publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    watch: NODE_ENV === DEVELOPMENT,
    devtool: NODE_ENV === DEVELOPMENT ? 'inline-source-map' : false,

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] //?keepUrl=true
        }, {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            options: { }
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'raw-loader'
        }, {
            test: /(\.less)|(\.css)$/i,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [{
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader?sourceMap',
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () {
                            return [
                                precss(),
                                autoprefixer()
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'less-loader'
                }],
                publicPath: './'
            })
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.[hash].js'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            path.join(__dirname, './src'),
            {}
        ),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.[hash].css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new CheckerPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'typescript',
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ].concat(NODE_ENV === PRODUCTION ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            warnings: false,
            unsafe: true,
            drop_console: false
        })
    ] : [
        //development
    ])
};
```

когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать проект (а он у меня почти пустой, пара полей ввода), то у меня на это тратится очень много времени. я согласен когда webpack компилирует первый раз. но когда я делаю правку в одном  файле, он опять все собирает и тратит 13-15 сек. имхо это много

текущий список vendor это минимум что мне понадобится, т.е. он будет расширяться.

можно сделать оптимизацию? чтобы vendor собирался только один раз. а сам проект собирался когда есть изменения (watch)?

Comment: нашел вот это. получилось сократить повторное время компиляции и составляет 1-2сек, это уже лучше  https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Answer (score 1):

Для разработки нужно использовать `devtool: 'eval'` либо `devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map'` если очень нужна сурсмапа. `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` слишком медленный для разработки. Для продакшена лучше собирать с `devtool: 'source-map'`. Исправьте в конфиге:

```
devtool: NODE_ENV === DEVELOPMENT ? 'eval' : 'source-map',
```

[Документация по devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)